# Application.main() to load context and start app but under a different port for tests within Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-test

I have Sonarqube complaining we're missing coverage for the application class, even though we already have something like.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = TestActiveProfileResolver.class)
class ApplicationTests extends BaseIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private OAuthController controller;

@Test
void contextLoads() {
    assertNotNull(controller);
}

}
```

Where BaseIntegrationTest start our testContainers.

So we've added:

```
@Test
public void main() {
   Application.main(new String[]{"--spring.port=8081",});
}
```

Which works for the coverage, but it will fail if the application is already running on our port 8080. Reason why we've adding the `"--spring.port=8081"` piece as well as
`(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`, to see if that would force the app to start under another port perhaps, but that won't do.

The other option I thought of was perhaps having a specific application.yml file under the test folder that points to a different port, but copying everything from our main application.yml file. Not sure if this is the best approach though as that file is quite big and constantly changing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the ports issue, but the way we managed to make the coverage pass was to separate the tests into two classes, as in:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = TestActiveProfileResolver.class)
class ApplicationTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private OAuthController controller;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertNotNull(controller);
    }
}
```

And

```
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = TestActiveProfileResolver.class)
class MainMethodCoverageTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void main() {
        Application.main(new String[]{});
    }
}
```